# ValueError: Mix of label input types (string and number)

Tags: python, xgboost

I'm trying to use the XGBoost algorithm. I have a dataset with 4 attributes (quat_1, quat_2, quat_3, quat_4) and a target that can have nine different values (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8) [image: this is the dataset's head]
I'm trying to implement an XGBoost algoritmh with this code:

```
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size = 0.33, random_state = 0, stratify = y)
sc_x = StandardScaler()
x_train = sc_x.fit_transform(x_train)
x_test = sc_x.transform(x_test)
pca = PCA(n_components=2, svd_solver='auto', whiten=True)
fit = pca.fit(x_test)
pca.fit(x_train)
print("Explained Variance: %s" % fit.explained_variance_ratio_)
print(fit.components_)
D_train = xgb.DMatrix(x_train, label=y_train)
D_test = xgb.DMatrix(x_test, label=y_test)
parameters = {'eta': 0.3, 'max_depth': 9, 'objective': 'multi:softprob', 'num_class': 9}
steps=20
classifier = xgb.train(parameters, D_train, steps)
preds = classifier.predict(D_test)
best_preds= np.asarray([np.argmax(line) for line in preds])
print("Precision = {}".format(precision_score(y_test, best_preds, average='macro')))
print("Recall = {}".format(recall_score(y_test, best_preds, average='macro')))
print("Accuracy = {}".format(accuracy_score(y_test, best_preds)))
```

But it results this error:
**ValueError: Mix of label input types (string and number)**
Someone could help me please?

Comment: the error is quite self explanatory. You have to force the dtypes of the columns to avoid mixed dtypes. All columns must be numeric. Check `pd.to_numeric`.

Comment: Are you sure this code produces the error? Do you at any point call `confusion_matrix`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be indicating that *the label has mixed dtypes*. Both the training samples and target should be numeric. If the data gets parsed or read incorrectly, use something like `pd.to_numeric` to force to a numeric dtype.

There are also some things that don't seem to make sense:

```
 D_test = xgb.DMatrix(x_test, label=y_test)
```

Why are you including `y_test` in the prediction `DMatrix`? `xgb.predict` will only return the predictions. You'll need `y_test` to check the metrics, but it serves no purpose as input to the model.

You also don't seem to be doing anything with the fitted `PCA` model, not sure if that was intended.

Comment: How can I make the PCA effective? Thank you

Comment: I don't have enough context about the problem to answer this question. But if you're not feeding the output components as features, they're definitely not serving any purpose @chiaragilli

Comment: Could work something like this: pca = PCA(n_components=2, svd_solver='auto', whiten=True)
pca.fit(x_train)
x_train = pca.transform(x_train)
x_test = pca.transform(x_test)

Answer (score 0):

it means that in your labels you have mixed types, labels should be numeric ideally.

check if you have more string in any column in your data, if there is string make it numerical.
say you have 3 groups a,b,c then you can give them categories 1,2,3.
the model works on numeric data, no strings must be provided.