# How can i solve "Mix of label input types (string and number)"?

Tags: python

[error description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hCbox.png)

[model_evaluate.py procedure description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3VRCu.png)

[test dataset description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OjarC.png)

weibo sentiment analysis procedure as follows:
How can i solve "Mix of label input types (string and number)"??
How can i solve "Mix of label input types (string and number)"??

```
#test dataset procedure
import json
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report

from util import dataset, test_file_path
from model_train import convert_example_to_feature
from transformers import TFBertForSequenceClassification

with open("{}_label.json".format(dataset), "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    labels = json.loads(f.read())

cls_model = model = TFBertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained('bert-base-chinese', num_labels=len(labels))
cls_model.load_weights("{}_cls.h5".format(dataset))

test_df = pd.read_csv(test_file_path).fillna(value="")

test_data = []
for i in range(test_df.shape[0]):
    label, content = test_df.iloc[i, :]
    test_data.append((content, label))

input_ids_list = []
token_type_ids_list = []
attention_mask_list = []
true_cls_labels = []

for review, label in test_data:
    bert_input = convert_example_to_feature(review)
    input_ids_list.append(bert_input['input_ids'])
    token_type_ids_list.append(bert_input['token_type_ids'])
    attention_mask_list.append(bert_input['attention_mask'])
    true_cls_labels.append(label)

print("first 10 true cls labels: ", true_cls_labels[:10])
test_ds = [np.array(input_ids_list), np.array(attention_mask_list), np.array(token_type_ids_list)]
predictions = cls_model.predict(test_ds).logits
label_ids = np.argmax(cls_model.predict(test_ds).logits, axis=1)
predict_cls_labels = [labels[_] for _ in label_ids]
print("first 10 predict cls labels: ", predict_cls_labels[:10])
print("result for model evaluate: \n")
***print(classification_report(true_cls_labels, predict_cls_labels, digits=2))***
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please add the information related to the question [as text and not as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question).

Comment: what is the output of print("first 10 true cls labels: ", true_cls_labels[:10]) and print("first 10 predict cls labels: ", predict_cls_labels[:10])

Comment: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,  1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, ]

Comment: ['喜悦', '低落', '低落', '厌恶', '愤怒', '厌恶', '厌恶', '愤怒', '厌恶', '厌恶', '厌恶', '厌恶', '喜悦', '厌恶', '愤怒', '喜悦', '厌恶', '喜悦', '低落', '厌恶', '愤怒', '厌恶', '愤怒', '喜悦', '愤怒', '愤怒', '厌恶', '厌恶', '厌恶', '愤怒', '厌恶', '喜悦', '厌恶', '愤怒', '愤怒', '低落', '厌恶', '低落', '厌恶', ]

Comment: this is first 10 true cls labels: ", true_cls_labels[:10]

Comment: this is  print("first 10 predict cls labels: ", predict_cls_labels[:10])

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is this. The true_cls_labels are saved by index not the value you want to represent, as you see in the output you commented.

[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, ]

and

['喜悦', '低落', '低落', '厌恶', '愤怒', '厌恶', '厌恶', '愤怒', '厌恶', '厌恶', '厌恶', '厌恶', '喜悦', '厌恶', '愤怒', '喜悦', '厌恶', '喜悦', '低落', '厌恶', '愤怒', '厌恶', '愤怒', '喜悦', '愤怒', '愤怒', '厌恶', '厌恶', '厌恶', '愤怒', '厌恶', '喜悦', '厌恶', '愤怒', '愤怒', '低落', '厌恶', '低落', '厌恶', ]

You input the label here:

```
for i in range(test_df.shape[0]):
    label, content = test_df.iloc[i, :]
    test_data.append((content, label))
```

Maybe this test_df.iloc[i, :] does not what you want, but I don't now how the test_data[] looks like. Maybe you wanted to do:

```
for i in test_df.shape[0]:
    label, content = test_df.loc[i, :]
    test_data.append((content, label))
```

Comment: I can solve this problem.As follows:for x in range(len(true_cls_labels)):
    if true_cls_labels[x]==0:
        true_cls_labels[x]="喜悦"
    elif true_cls_labels[x]==1:
        true_cls_labels[x]="愤怒"
    elif true_cls_labels[x]==2:
        true_cls_labels[x]="厌恶"
    elif true_cls_labels[x]==3:
        true_cls_labels[x]="低落"  The mostly reason is different data tyes.I transform data types.

Comment: For such applikationen a switch case can be used and I still think you could solve it by changeing the .loc function. But if your solution works its ok

Answer (score 0):

This error means you have a mixed data type in your labels. You have to make sure the data type of the columns are the same (e.g., you can use `pd.to_numeric` to force the dtype to be numeric.

Please see this similar question: [ValueError: Mix of label input types (string and number)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64712106/valueerror-mix-of-label-input-types-string-and-number#:%7E:text=it%20means%20that%20in%20your,no%20strings%20must%20be%20provided.)